# How to streamline while loops for infinite cycle with pyautogui

Tags: python, while-loop, pyautogui

I've lurked on SO for a little while, but all of the existing posts I've seen haven't been able to help me. I'm currently teaching myself python, so I apologize if this is an easy fix I'm not seeing.

My objective with this piece of code is to cycle through tabs in a browser using pyautogui.hotkey. It takes user input for number of tabs to cycle through, and executes the pyautogui command.

My issue, however, is that I can't manage to create a looping for or while loop.

I've played around with `should_restart` variables, `for i in range(x)` etc etc, but I'm just not seeing my fix.

The code below is essentially what I want to streamline together.

My idealized flow is:

Take `input` -> increase `tabcounter` by 1 until it equals `input` -> reset `tabcounter`-> rinse & repeat.

```
numberofTabs = input('How many tabs do you have? \n')

tabcounter = 0

while int(tabcounter) < int(numberofTabs):
    tabcounter = tabcounter+1
    pyautogui.hotkey('alt', str(tabcounter))
    break

while int(tabcounter) == int(numberofTabs):
    tabcounter = 0
```

I want this code to loop until I interrupt it, or for a lengthy period of time.

Thank you in advance. I appreciate the help!

EDIT: After reworking it, and wrapping my code in a loop, I came up with this:

````
loopcount = input('How many times do you want this to loop?')

time.sleep(5)

count = 0
for i in range(int(loopcount)):
    while count < int(numberofTabs):
        count += 1
        pyautogui.hotkey('alt', str(count))
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        count = 0```
````

Comment: What about wrapping the two while loops with another one looking for input able to iterrupt it?

Comment: I didn't originally consider wrapping the two, and with the benefit of hindsight I know how I should have started it. Your advice got me thinking that the loop function has to wrap the operation itself, so I came up with my edit up above that works well enough for now at least. Thanks!